# Temporary failure in name resolution channel 2 django

Tags: django, django-channels

I have implemented channel2 in my django project , after some time i start it i have received this error on my server , i have apache on ubuntu for my code.

```
2019-02-12 10:30:51,863 ERROR    Exception inside application: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in _call_
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 59, in await_many_dispatch
    await task
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    result = task.result()
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 429, in receive
    real_channel
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 484, in receive_single
    index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 324, in _brpop_with_clean
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 820, in _aenter_
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 70, in pop
    conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 178, in create_redis
    loop=loop)
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 108, in create_connection
    timeout, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/var/www/RPG/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 19, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 739, in create_connection
    infos = f1.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here i attach a image which solve the problem but i need to find better solution.I don't think it's a properway to do this.

[image]

Comment: It's not easy to tell since you haven't shown any code but it seems there's a problem in DNS resolution for your redis domain

Comment: @Ken4scholars, check attached image , it solve my problem , but i dont think so its a appropriate solution.

Comment: Just as I suggested, it is a DNS problem and not really a Django channels issue. You need to properly setup the DNS server on your host machine

Comment: @Ken4scholars, do you have any document , which i can follow to setup DNS on my host machine ?

Comment: Well I don't know the particular issue you have with your DNS but you can do some googling